# LinearSVC and LogisticRegression are equivalent?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, svm, logistic-regression

I am comparing performance of LinearSVC and LogisticRegression of scikit.learn on textual data. I am using LinearSVC with 'l2' penalty and 'squared_hinge' loss. I use LogisticRegression  with 'l1' penalty. However I find that their performance is near identical on my data sets (in terms of classification accuracy, precision/recall etc., as well as running times). This can't be sheer coincidence, and leads me to suspect that these are in fact identical implementations. Is that the case?

If I am to compare LogisticRegression with a support vector based implementation (that can handle multiclass data) which class in scikit.learn should I use?

Here's my code

```
scorefunc = make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta = 1, pos_label = None) 
splits = StratifiedShuffleSplit(data.labels, n_iter = 5, test_size = 0.2)

params1 = {'penalty':['l1'],'C':[0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0]}
lr = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), param_grid = params1, cv = splits, n_jobs = 5, scoring = scorefunc)
lr.fit(data.combined_mat, data.labels)
print lr.best_params_, lr.best_score_

>> {'penalty': 'l1', 'C': 1.0} 0.91015049974


params2 = {'C':[0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0], 'penalty':['l2']}
svm = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(), param_grid = params2, cv = splits, n_jobs = 5, scoring = scorefunc)
svm.fit(data.combined_mat, data.labels)
print svm.best_params_, svm.best_score_

>> {'penalty': 'l2', 'C': 1.0} 0.968320989681
```

Comment: Please show us the data on which you get the near identical results.

Comment: @galath Sorry, the dataset is proprietary. But even otherwise it is a fairly high dimensional data set with many classification problems to be solved. Can't think of a way I could provide a summary of the data matrix either...

Comment: Could you show the code you use? Thanks.

Comment: @galath updated my question with code. thanks for your help !

Comment: Please add the output, and the selected `C` parameter in the two cases.

Comment: It is not strange that they have similar performance although they are not equivalent.

Comment: @galath updated. the differences I am seeing are mostly only in 2nd decimal places.

Comment: @yangjie the scikit-lean page says that the LinearSVC is  "implemented in terms of liblinear". And that LogisticRecression "implements regularized logistic regression using the liblinear library, newton-cg and lbfgs solvers". This leads me to suspect that for some reasons, in my case I am running liblinear in either case internally !!

Comment: @andy Yes they are both implemented using Liblinear, but that's because Liblinear library supports both linear SVM and logistic regression. Technically, they are still different.